# Managed MongoDB service (AZ cosmos DB/Atlas) vs K8s MongoDB on a stateful set?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-cosmosdb, azure-aks, mongodb-atlas

Hoping to get your thoughts and discussion (trying to decide what would be best to deploy my app)

Why would someone deploy their own MongoDB server in K8s with all the complexity involved with a stateful set, when they can use a managed MongoDB service such as MongoDB atlas or Azure CosmosDB?

What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Cost/Maintenance?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic here, as you're asking opinions, and there's really no objective way to answer this. As for cost and maintenance, that should all be captured within the respective database documentation.